# Restrict records of a model [Odoo]

Tags: python, odoo, record, odoo-8

I need to list partners in one my views so I used the model 'res.partner'.

```
     <record id="view_res_partner_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
          <field name="name">res.partner.tree</field>
          <field name="model">res.partner</field>
          <field name="arch" type="xml">
              <tree string="Contacts" edit="false" create="false" delete="false">
                  <field name="display_name"/>
                  <button name="generate" type="object" string="Générer" icon="oe_highlight"/>
              </tree>
          </field>
      </record>
```

This works well but every partners are listed. I would like to only list partners that got services. (Custom module services)

I would have done in the XML something like:

```
domain="[('display_name', 'in', 'select display_name from module_services')]"
```

Do you know how to perform this?

Edit:
I added this to my model ('res.partner')

```
got_services = fields.Boolean('Got services', compute='_compute_services')

 @api.multi
 def _compute_services(self):
     for record in self:
         self.env.cr.execute("SELECT * FROM module_service WHERE id = %d;" % record.id)
         res = self.env.cr.fetchall()
         record.got_services = False if not res else True
```

And modified my view:

```
     [...]
     <field name="display_name" domain="[('got_services', '=', True)]"/>
     <field name="got_services"/>
     [...]
```

got_services is set to True only if the customer got services (good) but all customers are listed anyway even with my domain.

Comment: You have to put a boolean on the res.partner object to set if the partner got services or not, then you could put this field in a domain.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define a new field in ***res.partner*** model according to your request.

You may create a *one2many* corresponding to the field ***res_partner_id*** in the custom_services model (I guess that is a many2one field), so you can do your domain filters easily.